# DnSpy decompiled output has syntax errors and can not be recompiled, in particular "<>f__switch$map1"

Tags: c#, decompiler, dnspy

I have a program which no longer has support and does not have source code available. So I decompiled it in order to make fixes, because the fixes required are substantial I decided to use dnSpy to export the decompiled code as a project, however there are some errors. in particular I see variable names that look like `<>f__switch$map1` where the can be any number in place of 1. I tried replacing them all with a more reasonable name and removing the <> but it doesn't appear to actually be declared anywhere? how can I fix these compiler errors in the output of dnSpy.

Comment: They're compiler generated names, deliberately invalid C# identifiers. You should find the pattern of where the identifier is used and match it up with coding patterns the require compiler generated code - e.g. anonymous types, async/iterator methods, etc.

Comment: On DnSpy settings -> Decompiler, the first few settings starting "Decompile..." should be checked

Comment: @Charlieface That doesn't seem to fix the problem. I tried both unchecked and checked and reopening and closing the assembly and dnspy.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is their any further reading on this? I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how i would even begin to match these up.

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case I was simply able to rename everything and then define it elsewhere, this worked and the program was able to compile.